# Binding to spacebar (32) keyup/down when pressed twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, lodash

I'm using Angular JS and I need to write a directive that will initiate a function ONLY when the spacebar (32) gets pressed twice in a row. The app has forms also and users might need to actually hit space twice in a textarea or input field, so we need to account for that as well. We also need to make sure the page doesn't scroll when pressing the spacebar, but doing event.preventDefault(); actually prevents the spacebar from being used to type a space in a form element. Any ideas as to how to accomplish this? Is it even possible? I might consider binding to a key combination instead if this is too difficult. Here is a sample of what I have so far:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  angular
    .module("app.spaceFunc")
    .directive("triggerFunc", triggerFunc);

  triggerFunc.$inject = ["$window"];
  /* @ngInject */
  function triggerFunc($window) {
    var directive = {
      link: link,
      restrict: "A"
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      var upHitOnce = false;
      angular.element($window).bind("keydown", function(event) {
        if ((event.keycode || event.which) === 32) {
          //Prevents page scrolling (spacebar default's behaviour)
          event.preventDefault();
          if (upHitOnce) {
            //some function gets executed here
            console.log("Spacebar pressed twice");
            upHitOnce = false;
          } else {
            upHitOnce = true;
          }
        } else {
          upHitOnce = false;
        }
      });
    }
  }
})();
```

The directive is attached to the body element

```
<body trigger-func>
```

Comment: I'm assuming you want the two presses to only be considered a double press if the time between the two presses is below a certain amount (otherwise how else would you determine that they don't just want to insert two spaces into the textarea?). It would be pretty simple to do using setTimeout - when the first space is pressed, set a boolean to true, when the timeout expires, set it to false. If a press comes in whilst the boolean is true, then you know spacebar has been clicked twice within the timeframe you've sent to setTimeout. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: @Jonah Yes, I forgot to mention that it should be timed to about 500ms.. I think that is fast enough so that the user can just do 2 spaces in a row. good observation, let me apply something like that and I'll update the question. Thanks

Comment: @jonah this is what I have so far https://plnkr.co/edit/2UHcncHpRi2Yc9yd1m6G?p=info what do you think